# Continuous treatment effect using twangContinuous

Tags: r

I was reading the tutorial for  twangContinuous here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twangContinuous/vignettes/briefTutorial.html

I loaded their dataset dat and say that there are two treatment groups A and B and there are different levels of tss_0 is their continuous exposure and represents a count of trauma symptoms. Both treatment groups include 0<=tss_0<=13.

```
0  0.1  0.2 0.88    1 1.16    2 2.31 2.33    3 3.45    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
A 1238    0    3    1   49    1   81    0    1   69    0   77   82   79   65   66   56   59   26   34   13
B 1307    1    0    0   33    0   68    2    0   82    1   81  101   91   64   53   43   39   16   10    8
```

If I want to define a treatment group as mother's with years of schooling>=12, does it make sense to estimate a continuous treatment effect using this package? I estimated all the teffects estimator (RA, IPW, IPWRA,AIPW, PSM, NNM) using stata teffects package where the treatment variable is binary so, I defined treatment=1 if mom's education>=12, otherwise treatment=0.
At first, I thought I could stick with the same treatment definition in the continuous treatment effect estimator but only considering mother's education at various levels like 12 years, 13 years, 14 years, 15 years, and so on. It's like comparing 'no drug' to different doses of the drug, or in this case, no high school graduation to various levels of mom's education, starting at 12 years.

However, upon examining the dataset associated with the twangContinuous package, I'm questioning whether my case is suitable for a continuous treatment effect estimator. Could someone please confirm if estimating continuous treatment effects makes sense for me or not? Any other related suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it sounds like you are asking for methodology help, your question might be better suited for stat exchange instead of stack overflow

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will post it on Stack Exchange then!